# Does clojure have a merge-if-exists function?

Tags: clojure

Does clojure have a `merge-if-exists` function to merge two maps,
like

```
(defn merge-if-exists [map1 map2])
```

return a new map containing all keys of `map1`, and if a key occurs in more than one map, use `map2`'s value of this key as return map value, else `map1`'s value.

e.g.

```
(merge-if-exists {:a 1 :b 2} {:b 3})
;=> {:a 1, :b 3}

(merge-if-exists {:a 1 :b 2} {:c 3})
;=> {:a 1, :b 2}

(merge-if-exists{:b 3} {:a 1 :b 2})
;=> {:b 2}
```

How to write this function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could define this with `merge` and `select-keys`:

```
(defn merge-if-exists [m1 m2]
  (merge m1 (select-keys m2 (keys m1))))

(merge-if-exists {:a 1 :b 2} {:b 3})
=> {:a 1, :b 3}
(merge-if-exists {:a 1 :b 2} {:c 3})
=> {:a 1, :b 2}
(merge-if-exists {:b 3} {:a 1 :b 2})
=> {:b 2}
```

Or a faster/more efficient version using `reduce-kv`:

```
(defn merge-if-exists [m1 m2]
  (reduce-kv
   (fn [m k v]
     (assoc m k (if-let [r (find m2 k)]
                  (val r)
                  v)))
   {}
   m1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it as follows:

```clj
(defn merge-keep-left [left right]
  (select-keys (merge left right) (keys left)))
```

This function is from a post from [Mark Needham](https://dzone.com/articles/clojure-merge-two-maps-only). He also showcases alternative implementation in the blogpost.